# get paragraph number (not line number) of paragraph in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, paragraph

I have a richtextbox which contains a large number of paragraphs.  (fyi : All paragraphs would be separated by vbCrlf)

I need to know the paragraph index at the cursor position.

It is easy to find the line index

```
    Dim line, index As Integer
    index = rtbScriptRTF.SelectionStart
    line = rtbScriptRTF.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
    txtTestLINE.Text = line
```

that is NOT what I'm looking for as a paragraph can easily occupy many lines.

Crazy thing is ... I saw a piece of code somewhere on these pages that does just that, but I can't find it anywhere!

Can anyone point me in the right direction or perhaps assist with the correct syntax?
thank you!

EDIT : I have added the used code, but now it is no longer possible to navigate the text using the keyboard arrows - is there a workaround?

```
Private Sub rtbScriptRTF_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbScriptRTF.KeyDown
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim lineNum As Integer

    rtbScriptRTF.Focus()
    rtbScriptRTF.SuspendLayout()
    rtbScriptRTF.WordWrap = False


    Index = rtbScriptRTF.SelectionStart
    lineNum = rtbScriptRTF.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
    txtTestLINE.Text = lineNum + 1

    rtbScriptRTF.WordWrap = True
    rtbScriptRTF.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: What defines a paragraph? A new line? Multiple new lines (if so how many)?

Comment: all the text until vbcrlf would be one paragraph, after vbcrlf another paragraph would start.  So potentially quite a large number of lines in one paragraph.  Sorry I did not seem to have made that clear. -- updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Unfortunately, you might have to set `richTextBox1.WordWrap = false` then `dim lineNum = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)` and back `richTextBox1.WordWrap = true` or get the positions of all `\n` (`VbLf`, char 10) chars until you have a value `> index` or get to the end of the text.

Comment: If you opt for the former method, set `[RichTextBox].SuspendLayout()`, then change the WordWrap property, get the line index, then `[RichTextBox].ResumeLayout()`, otherwise the control will visibly flicker.

Comment: @Jimi - thanks for this!  for some reason though, I can no longer navigate the text using arrows.(arrow movements don't seem to be registering)  which bit in the code causes this and is there a workaround?

Comment: There's nothing that causes this behavior. Make sure the Control has the focus. Anyway, I don't know what code you actually wrote.

Comment: @jimi -     added my code to the question - I did not expect the arrows not to work anymore.

Comment: If you really really want to use that code in a key press event, use the KeyUp event, not the KeyDown. Remove `rtbScriptRTF.Focus()` and change this: `txtTestLINE.Text = (lineNum + 1).ToString()` (shows that you have Option Strict Off, very bad). You shouldn't use this kind of code in key press events. Try to find another use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native RichEdit control, that the WinForm RichTextBox wraps, supports a subset of the [Text Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/text-object-model).

> The TOM defines a substantial set of text manipulation interfaces. Text solutions such as Microsoft Word and rich edit controls support the TOM feature set.

Add a project COM reference to "tom" to gain access to the interface definitions in your .Net project. Then you obtain a reference to the TOM [ITextDocument interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tom/nn-tom-itextdocument) by sending then [EM_GETOLEINTERFACE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getoleinterface) to the control.  Once you have the document reference, you can navigate the document similar to using MS Word's Object model.

In the example below (create a new WinForm project with a `RichTextBox` and label on the form), the `SelectionChanged` event is used to display the number of the selected paragraph in the label.  Note that as this COM, the numbering starts at index one(1) not zero(0).  The document reference ,stored in the variable "doc") is obtained when the RichTextBox handle is created.

```
' add project COM reference to "tom" 

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
  Private doc As tom.ITextDocument
  Private comCallCount As Int32 = 1 ' used to force GC to cleanup unreferenced COM object

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    PopulateRTB()
  End Sub

  Private Sub PopulateRTB()
    With RichTextBox1
      .AppendText("Paragraph 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, solum lobortis pri id, vocent volumus praesent nam ut. Impetus aliquip quo at. Eos nisl veniam fierent an, cu dictas veritus vivendo mea, ei sea eruditi prodesset percipitur. Duo in case eirmod adipiscing, qui habemus scriptorem id. Mei nihil facilisis cu, id sumo laboramus consectetuer vel. No nostrud aliquid quo. Nam doming melius scripta eu." & Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText("Paragraph 3: An pri consul adversarium, ea mel semper quaeque complectitur. Mea te solet concludaturque, ei mucius albucius sit. Per no lucilius detraxit adipisci, ut tamquam delenit cotidieque cum. Mea putent apeirian sapientem cu. Per saperet accumsan rationibus at." & Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText("Paragraph 5: Velit tollit voluptua pri ut. Convenire honestatis no nam, nulla legere salutatus at ius. Ea duo nisl everti aliquid, dolore aperiam tractatos te duo, quaeque veritus ad vim. At vim consul laoreet, inermis iudicabit et vim." & Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText("Paragraph 7: Altera efficiendi ad qui, ne quo viris moderatius. Idque singulis suavitate ea vix, vis at ancillae detraxit contentiones, has constituam sadipscing et. Eos et iudico corrumpit, augue nominavi ad mel. Impetus equidem eu duo. Ea sale legimus dignissim vix." & Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
      .AppendText("Paragraph 9: Et quodsi oblique iudicabit pro, an nam augue consulatu, ad cum graece malorum mediocritatem. Vivendo ullamcorper vim et, maiestatis accommodare sit cu. Duo vocent deleniti et, nec ei congue melius tamquam, modo phaedrum no sea. Ius at velit augue soleat." & Environment.NewLine)
    End With
  End Sub

  Private Sub RichTextBox1_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.HandleCreated
    Const WM_USER As Int32 = &H400
    Const EM_GETOLEINTERFACE As Int32 = WM_USER + 60
    If doc IsNot Nothing Then
      Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc)
      doc = Nothing
    End If
    SendMessage(New HandleRef(Me, RichTextBox1.Handle), EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, IntPtr.Zero, doc)
  End Sub

  Private Sub RichTextBox1_HandleDestroyed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.HandleDestroyed
    If doc IsNot Nothing Then
      Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc)
      doc = Nothing
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub RichTextBox1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.SelectionChanged
    Label1.Text = $"In paragraph number: {doc.Selection.GetIndex(tom.tomConstants.tomParagraph)}"
    comCallCount += 1
    If comCallCount = 10 Then
      CleanupUnreferencedCOM()
      comCallCount = 1
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub CleanupUnreferencedCOM()
    Do
      GC.Collect()
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Loop While Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup
  End Sub

  <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
  Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As tom.ITextDocument) As IntPtr
  End Function

End Class
```

There is also the [Managed Wrapper for the Text Object Model (TOM)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190527070548/https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/709) library by Bradley Smith that makes working with object model a bit easier.  If you elect to use this library, do note that the author added functionality via managed code and there exists both zero and one based indexing in the library.  So make sure you read either the Intellisense documentation or the main project documentation to avoid surprises.